# Way to aggregate large influxes of email

Tags: linux, php, email, bash

we are setting up a monitoring solution that'll utilize email notifications. However we have already seen that there are instances in which certain problems will affect large clusters of nodes effectively causing the monitoring solution to mailbomb the mailbox notifications go to. Does anyone know of a solution out there we could use to pipe notification emails to such that when large influxes come in it'll aggregate all the emails into one email and just send that out instead of each individually?

Comment: This needs to be addressed by the monitoring solution, not by trying to intercept and aggregate multiple emails.

Comment: And if it's not....?

Comment: If it's not, this question looks a lot like a product recommendation request, and since those are off-topic for SF, it might get closed.

Comment: This isnt a product recommendation request this is a inquiry as to the best way to work with a shortcoming in a product. Has nobody really ever had to do this before? I find that extremely hard to believe.

Answer (score 2):

If your monitoring solution is generating so much output that it is DoSing you, you really need to address that.  If you actually have that much monitoring data either you are generating data you don't need for anything, or your entire environment is falling down about your ears and you need to fix it stat.

You cannot modify email without receiving email.  However, if for some reason you do have a use case I'm not thinking of where generating catastrophic deluges of email is in fact appropriate, you may want to consider setting up an additional mail domain with its own MX, positioned very close to the monitoring server(s), to host the inboxes.  You could then use your mailbox rule solution of choice to filter these notifications, or possibly create a script that receives and reformats the mail and passes it on (though honestly this would be better addressed at the source).  I don't know of any products that do this (and if there are, recommending one would be off topic anyway).

This is a very uncommon need, and it seems to me that it would more likely result from misconfiguration than anything.  If you're generating so much output it causes systemic problems it's probably too much output for anyone to read, much less action.  Increase your granularity and your thresholds.

Answer (score 1):

If you've ever been on pager duty, you've probably needed to solve this problem.  Maybe you should google 'pager duty'.

Or you could setup your monitoring solution to follow dependencies.